# How to disable HP Envy light sensor auto-dimming

Tags: power-management

I swapped my windows OS for Ubuntu a couple of months ago. I had no idea HP Envy came with this annoying feature described here...
http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-envy-hdx/515979-envy-15-random-screen-dimming.html

But... I have no idea how to toggle the sensor now that I don't have windows installed.

Comment: I haven't found any option to toggle screen dimming